# Serialize Integer[]

Tags: java, arrays, soap, integer

I have a Android APP and a SOAPWebservice. I'm trying to send between their a Integer array but the Android Logcat says:

```
06-17 15:32:34.355: W/System.err(3107): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [Ljava.lang.Integer;@42046ff8
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:664)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:649)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:595)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:573)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:658)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:555)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write  (SoapEnvelope.java:205)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:134)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:144)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
06-17 15:32:34.365: W/System.err(3107):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
```

How I can send a bunch of Integers if I can't serialitze the data?

**ANDROID CODE (AsyncTask)**

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {

    try {       

        OSS_APPServiceCredentials wsc = new OSS_APPServiceCredentials("startUpdate");

        request = new SoapObject(wsc.init().get(1), wsc.init().get(0));

        request.addProperty("ParameterA", (String)params[0]);           
        request.addProperty("ParameterB", (Integer[])params[1]);

        envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        OSS_PermitAllSSLConnections.allowAllSSL();
        KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE(wsc.init().get(3),Integer.parseInt(wsc.init().get(5)), wsc.init().get(4), Integer.parseInt(wsc.init().get(6)));

        androidHttpTransport.call(wsc.init().get(2), envelope); 
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        Integer res = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());

        return res;
    } 

    catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I tried to do this:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] bytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(permissions);

int[] a = new int[bytes.length / 4];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asIntBuffer().get(a);
```

But Eclipse (In the WebService) say this error, and I dont know why!

```
The method wrap(byte[]) is undefined for the type ByteBuffer
```

**EDIT:**

Finally I solved the problem. Only I need import:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I update the post with my code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert int[] into byte[] with ByteBuffer

```
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(a.length * 4);
    bb.asIntBuffer().put(a);
    byte[] bytes = bb1.array();
```

send byte[] to server and convert it back to int[]

```
    int[] a = new int[bytes.length / 4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asIntBuffer().get(a);
```

Comment: This requires that the other end does read in big endian but that is likely to be the case anyway. +1.

Comment: may be it's better to use `base64`? `int[] <-> base64`

Comment: I update the original post. I have and error, and i dont know why!
You can help me please? Thanks!